# tab and whitespace characters in sql select

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm on Rails 4 and am doing this simplified version of a left outer join in a model. For readability I have some line breaks and tabs mid-string in a few parameters for other devs I work with.

```
    self.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN answers 
                ON questions.id = answers.question_id').
                where(test_id: test_id).
                where("answers.student_id = ? 
                OR answers.student_id IS NULL", student_id).
                select('questions.*, answers.text 
                AS answer_text')
```

Which becomes the below code when I tag #to_sql on the end. (I added the line breaks for readability in the example)

```
  "SELECT questions.*, answers.text\n
  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAS answer_text 
  FROM \"questions\" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN answers\n
  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tON questions.id = answers.question_id 
  WHERE \"tests\".\"test_id\" = 1 
  AND (answers.student_id = 1\n
  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tOR answers.student_id IS NULL)"
```

My concern is that active record is inserting the "\t\t\t\t" and "\n" characters into the SQL query. I am hoping that someone can tell me whether or not this will be an issue down the road or if I can be safe submitting this for production. The queries are functioning properly and passing all tests so that is not an issue at the moment.

I could run the parameters as unbroken strings, but those are the most thick pieces. Another option is to just do raw SQL, but I would rather not for codebase consistency.

Without the line breaks in the editor this a major eyesore and thick method call.

Again queries are behaving like I need, just curious if there may be consequences.